# Comparing two timestamp strings in C++

Tags: c++, difference

I have two timestamps stored as string variables.  The timestamps are in the format dd/mm/yyyy-hh:mm:ss
I am trying to find the difference in seconds between the two timestamps (ignoring the dates).

(I haven't assigned strings to a and b but they hold a timestamp each)

It always outputs 0 for the number of seconds difference and I can't work out why.

```
std::string a, b; // hold timestamps
struct tm t, t1;
double seconds;

t.tm_hour = stoi(a.substr(11,2)); // stoi() cast substring to int
t.tm_min = stoi(a.substr(14,2));
t.tm_sec = stoi(a.substr(17,2));

t1.tm_hour = stoi(b.substr(11,2));
t1.tm_min = stoi(b.substr(14,2));
t1.tm_sec = stoi(b.substr(17,2));

seconds = difftime(mktime(&t1), mktime(&t));
std::cout<<seconds;
```

Comment: `std::cout << t.tm_sec << ',' << t1.tm_sec << '\n'` will likely be educational.

Comment: I've printed the values of both `t` and `t1` during testing and they both match the values of the initial timestamp strings.  It doesn't seem to calculate the difference using `difftime(mktime(&t1), mktime(&t));`

Comment: And the same for the results of the two `mktime` calls ? As written the non-time fields of your structs are indeterminate. I.e they're garbage, with only your time-info being saved. I'd be surprised of `mktime` is even succeeding. If *neither* does, they both return -1 and the diff would be zero.

Comment: I hadn't tested the two `mktime` calls, however now that I have they both produce `-1` as you suggested.
Could you advise on what I should try next? thanks

Comment: populate the struct with valid *date* info before setting up your time values. since you're not interested in date info (which may well be a mistake but thats another issue), `struct tm 1{}, tm1{};` would be a good place to start.

Comment: I've populated the stucts with day, month and year in the same way as I did for time.  Is this correct or am I completely off? I still get result of zero.

Comment: That's totally how I would do it as well. (barring using a completely different time library). So long as the values are in-range, what you're doing should work if all the members are properly initialized.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas.  What time library would you normally use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code after the defintions and before the assignments

```
// initialize time structures with all the details for 'now'
time_t ts;
time( &ts );
t = * localtime( &ts );
t1 = t;
```

Comment: That cured my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hardcoded substring values (1 minute vs 11 minute might make you go off if 01 notation isn't used... and you have months ,days and hours also to take into account).

Instead of hardcoding the offset try to go after the unique characters (for you to get the "seconds" , take account the only the string after the 2nd occurrence of ":" ).

Comment: I'm only using the hardcoded values to get it working.  I will make it more flexible after.  With test timestamps using the same formating `a = "21/01/2014-20:14:14";` and `b = "21/01/2014-20:15:14"`
`seconds` should result in a value of `60` however the line of code containing `difftime` doesn't seem to calculate this.  Instead it gives 0.

Comment: well, if you substract the seconds, you will get indeed 0 (because it's 14-14). What's the code of your difftime function ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use CTime to work with timestamp.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/

You can use this for storage and later, if you need, convert to string.

Comment: It is not `CTime` (which would be an MFC class), and since they are already using `difftime`, I think they know about the header.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great reason to start with the [**Boost**](http://www.boost.org/) libraries, because Boost.Date_Time has exactly what you need. See the documentation about [time durations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration).

Here is an example program:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration1 = boost::posix_time::duration_from_string("10:11:12");
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration2 = boost::posix_time::duration_from_string("10:12:15");

    std::cout << (duration2 - duration1).total_seconds() << "\n";
}
```

Output: 63

Since you are already using `substr` and `std::stoi`, it should be easy for you to get the proper substrings from `a` and `b` to be passed to `boost::posix_time::duration_from_string`.